# Can I place signature Tab dynamically in docusign documents

Tags: java, api, docusignapi

I am using docusing for signing of documents. I am using Java coding for calling docosign API. Its work properly, 
But I want to know that if have any process to place the signature tab dynamically as per content of the page.
Means where the page content is end the signature place will come just after that.

Answer (score 1):

There are three strategies for specifying DocuSign tabs dynamically on a document:

1) x/y coordinates.

2) anchor strings. DocuSign will scan the document for a specified string and place the tab at a specified x/y offset from the string:  https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Anchoring%20Tabs.htm

3) If the PDF already has Abobe Form Fields specified on the document, DocuSign can convert those fields into equivalent DocuSign tabs:  https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm