# Can I place DocuSign signing object without anchor string?

Tags: docusignapi

My application is fairly simple: a user can upload a document from their computer, see an image of the document to scale on the webpage, and finally "add a signature" to the document.

The point at which the user clicks to add a signature is recorded with x/y location and page number.

The "Send" button should gather those points and apply a "sign here tab" from DocuSign and, of course, send to the specified recipient.

I can't find the documentation that would give me the ability to add a signing tab solely on the x/y coordinate. As suggested here: [Can I place signature Tab dynamically in docusign documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284760/can-i-place-signature-tab-dynamically-in-docusign-documents)

Is this possible?
How might that signing object look?

Comment: I'm have a same problem and don't now how resolve... Please tell us if you can do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is C# code, but you can do that in other ways. Most tabs object have xPosition and yPosition properties you can use to specify coordinates.

```
        SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere
        {
            XPosition = "170",
            YPosition = "418",
            Optional = "false",
            StampType = "signature",
            DocumentId = "3",
            PageNumber = "1",
            RecipientId = "1",
            Name = "SignHere",
        };
        SignHere signHere2 = new SignHere
        {
            XPosition = "220",
            YPosition = "418",
            Optional = "false",
            StampType = "signature",
            DocumentId = "3",
            PageNumber = "1",
            RecipientId = "2",
            Name = "SignHere"
        };
```